# Proper Velocity $v$ Relative Velocity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, velocity, inertial-frames

I understand the proper velocity is the velocity as measured by the traveler, and relative velocity as measured by the observer.

Relative velocity is limited to $c$, but is that also true of proper velocity?  Theoretically, of course, assuming a sufficient energy source was available. And what would be the effects on the traveler if it was possible for proper velocity to exceed $c$?

Comment: Proper velocity is not really a thing; anyone measures themselves to move at zero velocity.

Comment: There is no such thing as proper velocity. Generaly what we call as proper velocity is the velocity ofan object measured by an observer on ground. It'l is used for practical purposes but it is still a relative velocity (relative to Earth)

Comment: Even traveler becomes at rest while finding velocity of another moving object. Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity) "the velocity of A in the coordinate system where **B is always at rest**", this means "Velocity of A with respect to B"

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as proper velocity, considering any motion, the concept of $Proper$ $Velocity$ is very ambiguous. As, whenever you try to quantify any velocity, you need any type of reference frame. And clearly, the measured velocity, is relative to that $reference$ $frame$. It might be the traveler or the observer, but still the measurement of velocity is totally relative.

And any type of velocity whatsoever, is limited to $c$, and proper velocity doesn't play any role at all, it is totally generalized a concept.

And theoretically if, the traveler reaches the velocity $c$, it's relative mass would blow up to infinity, and according the Mass-Energy Conservation law of the universe, anything cannot have infinite mass, and any matter particle can never reach speed of light.

as:  $$ m\prime = \frac{m}{\sqrt {1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$,

where $m\prime$ is the relative mass of the particle, and $m$ is called the rest mass of that, and clearly for $v$ approaching $c$, $m\prime$ approaches $\ \infty$

and there were one critical $unclarity$ in your question:

You're saying the velocity measured by the traveler is the proper velocity, even if I take that true, the proper velocity of the traveler is always 0. Because, the traveler is measuring his own velocity then.

I hope this made your concept clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe by Relative Velocity you mean coordinate velocity which is defined as
$$v^i=\frac{dx^i}{dt}$$
Which obviously has a limit. And when you say it can not exceed $c$ I guess you mean the speed.
Then by proper speed I assume you mean Relativistic Four Velocity, which is defined as
$$U^\mu =\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$$
And if you calculate it's magnitude you will always get that $U^2=c^2$. That means that four velocity's magnitude can never change

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what other answers are saying, proper velocity is definitely a thing (see wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity).

Proper velocity is typically defined to be the displacement measured by an observer divided by the proper time measured by the traveler.

$$\text{proper velocity}=\eta=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta \tau}$$

And to answer your question, yes, the proper velocity as defined above can be larger than c. I'll prove it below (note that regular velocity is $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$).

$$\eta=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta \tau}=\gamma \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

So if we set $\eta=c$ we find that

$$c=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
$$1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}=\frac{v^2}{c^2}$$
$$1=2\frac{v^2}{c^2}$$
$$v=\frac{c}{\sqrt 2}$$

So the proper velocity will be larger than c for all velocities larger than $\frac{c}{\sqrt 2}$. There is nothing magical that happens to the traveler at this particular speed and there is no violation of relativity. Special relativity demands that no object have a larger regular velocity than c, it places no upper limit on the proper velocity.